# insert method for Priority Queue using Linked Lists

Tags: java

Firstly I feel I should mention this is for an assignment. I'm not looking for a direct code answer just to point me in the right direction. We have been asked to implement a Priority Queue in a linked list.

I am struggling to write the first part of the insert() function. In the code I try to check if the `head` contains anything, if not it set's the `head` to `pqItem`. It does this, but when insert is called again for a second insert it doesn't recognise that `head` already has a `PQueueItem` in it and just overrides `head` instead of ignoring `if (this.head == null)`. Am I not settting `head` correctly?

**PQueue Class**

```
package ci284.ass1.pqueue;

public class PQueue<T> {

private PQueueItem<T> head;
public static enum ORDER {
    ASC, DESC;
}
public static ORDER DEFAULT_ORDER;
private ORDER order;

public PQueue() {
    this.order = DEFAULT_ORDER;
    head = null;
}

...

public void insert(T data, int priority) {
    PQueueItem<T> pqItem = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
    PQueueItem<T> temp;
    PQueueItem<T> prev;
    System.out.println("This is pqItem   " + pqItem);

    if (this.order == ORDER.DESC || this.order == DEFAULT_ORDER){
        if (this.head != null){
            System.out.println("Not null   " + head);
            if (priority <= head.getPriority()){

            }
            else if (priority > head.getPriority()){
                prev = head;
                System.out.println(prev);
                head.setNext(head);
                prev = pqItem;
                System.out.println(prev);
            }
        }
        if (this.head == null){
            System.out.println("Null    " + head);
            this.head = pqItem;
            System.out.println("Null    " + head);
        }
    }
}
```

**PQueueItem Class**

```
package ci284.ass1.pqueue;

public class PQueueItem<T> {

private int priority;
private T data;
private PQueueItem<T> next;

public PQueueItem(T data, int priority) {
    this.data = data;
    this.priority = priority;
}
public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}
public T getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public PQueueItem<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}
public void setNext(PQueueItem<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("[%s,%d]", data.toString(), priority);
}

}
```

**JUnit Test for insert**

```
@Test
public void testInsertStart(){
    PQueue<String> pq = new PQueue<String>();
    pq.insert("1",2);
    String head = pq.pop();
    assertEquals(head, "1");
    System.out.println("Worked");
    pq.insert("Hiya",3);
    assertEquals(head, "Hiya");
}
```

The test returns:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<1> but was:<Hiya>
```

and the console reads:

```
This is pqItem   [1,2]
Null    null
Null    [1,2]
Worked
This is pqItem   [Hiya,3]
Null    null
Null    [Hiya,3]
```

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you're making the two calls to `insert`?

Comment: Added the calls

Comment: Can you explain me in english what should happen `if (priority > head.getPriority())`?

Comment: If ``pqItem`` priority is higher than the ``head`` priority it should replace move ``head`` down the list and insert ``pqItem`` where ``head`` was.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question. That is not allowed. cc @petermcneil

Comment: Don't vandalize your question. If it's an assignment and it's not allowed, you should've thought about that *before* posting the question.

Comment: Also, vandalism does not help you anyways because the post's revision history is public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some <s>pseudocode</s> code. (I have tested it by creating a queue)

```
public void insert(int priority, int data) {
    Item item = new Item(priority, data);

    if (head == null) {
        head = item;
        item.setNext(null);
    } else {
        Item next = head;
        Item prev = next;

        do {
            if (priority > next.getPriority()) {
                // break and insert
                break;
            }
            prev = next;
            next = next.getNext();
        } while (next != null);

        item.setNext(next);
        if (item.getPriority() > head.getPriority()) {
            head = item;
        } else prev.setNext(item);
    }
}
```

You had the following problems in your insert method:

```
prev = head;
head.setNext(head);
prev = pqItem;
```

What does this piece of code even do? Here is what it does:

[image: bad code]

You also did not consider the case in which you have more than two items in the queue. Imagine you have 5 items in the queue. And now you want to insert `pqItem` in the queue. `pqItem` has the least priority so it will get inserted at the end of the queue, right? Therefore, you need to traverse the queue (list) in order to get to the last item.

Comment: Firstly thank you for responding! I changed the insert method that was wrong to this:

    ``prev = head;
    head = pqItem;
    head.setNext(prev);``

Comment: Sorry edit failed. I tried implementing your method to check if ``head`` is null but it still finds ``head`` as null when insert is called again. 

I don't understand why it won't keep the ``PQueueItem`` when called again, I can't be attributing it correctly.

Comment: @petermcneil It should work. Maybe something is wrong with your pop method? Also, you haven't written anything what will happen when the `priority <= head.getPriority( )`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tinkered around a bit more and implemented the ``priority <= head.getPriority()`` method and it works. Thanks a lot again saved me a lot of stress.