# How to sort a linked list in alphabetical order using Java?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am doing an library inventory system, so I was supposed to sort the name inside the Node into alphabetical order. I have bookname, author, isbn number, number of copies and genre, all these information I store inside a class.

I do wrote the code for it to sort alphabetically, but it didn't work. 
Could someone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Here is my Linked List class contain insert and display method:

```
 public class LinkedList
{
Node node = new Node();
static Node head;

public LinkedList()
{
    head=null;
}

public Node getHead()
{
    return head;
}

public static void addNode(Data data)
{
     Node newNode = new Node(data, head);

    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        newNode.setNext(null);
    } else {
        Node next = head;
        Node prev = next;
    do {
        if (data.name.compareTo(next.data.name) < 0) {
            break;
        }
        prev = next;
        next = next.getNext();
    } while (next != null);

    newNode.setNext(next);
    if (data.name.compareTo(next.data.name) < 0) {
        head = newNode;
    } else prev.setNext(newNode);
}
}

public static String displayNode()
{
    Node current = head;
    String output = "";
    while(current != null){       
        output+=current.data.toString();
        current = current.next;  
    }
    return output;
}
```

Here is my Node class:

```
public class Node 
{
Data data;
Node next;

public Node()
{
    next = null;
}

Node(Data data, Node next)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

public Object getData()
{
    return data;
}

public Node getNext()
{
    return next;   
}

public void setNext(Node next)
{
    this.next=next;
}
}
```

Here is my Data class:

```
public class Data {
LinkedList list;
String name;
String author;
int isbn;
int number;
String genre;

public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.number = number;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String toString()
{
    return("Book Name: "+name+"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nISBN Number: "+isbn+"\nNumber of Copies: "+number+"\nGenre: "+genre+"\n\n");
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Here is my Iterator class which I used to display the list:

```
public class DisplayIterator
{
LinkedList list;
static Node current;
static Node newNode;

DisplayIterator(Node newNode)
{
    this.newNode = newNode;
    current = list.head;
}

public static boolean hasNext()
{
    if(current == null){
        return false;
    }
    else if (current.next == null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static Node next()
{
    if(hasNext()){
        current = current.next;
    }
    return current;
}

public static void remove(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("It is read-only.");        
}

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're adding the not to the top of the list without any order. Your *while* loop is just running inside the linked list until it is ordered. If you want to sort the linked list you should add the new node on the right place, not always on the top. But, if I can ask, why you don't use a *Collection*?

Comment: Any reason why you reinvent the wheel? Use TreeSet and Comparable or Comparator interface. They do the same but are part of the Java Lib.

Comment: Of course he should be using a `Collection`, but my guess is that the assignment requires writing a custom linked list implementation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes this exercise do requires to write a custom linked list implementation.

Comment: @MarioSantini  This is a custom linked list therefore can't use the Collection method. I see, so I should get rid of `newNode.next = head` and `head=newNode` right ? How should I change?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, by bis teacher...

Comment: @Acetamide yes, but not only, anyway you have already an answer.

Comment: @Acetamide I answered a very similar question here:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/40637006/2235972   Just change the `if` condition to this:    `if (data.name.compareTo(next.data.name) < 0)`

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet There is two if statement in the code, I guess I have to change both?

Comment: @Acetamide Yes, you should change both. It should work. Let me know

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet both to the same statement I assumed ? Both to `if (data.name.compareTo(next.data.name) < 0)` ?

Comment: @Acetamide Yes. It means that `data.name` is less than `next.data.name`

Comment: Your current code has numerous problems, and you should not be looking for a quick fix here.  With regard to the actual question, did your prof ask you to insert _and_ sort the list, or just to insert while maintaining order?  The latter is the only option which makes any sense to me.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet It did sort but when I enter 3 data, it only display 2 data...?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen We are being told to insert, delete and search the list. Then the list should be in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Acetamide Maybe you have some implementation problem in your print method or something. I've entered duplicate values and it still shows me all the values in sorted order. Also, post your `Node` class and print methods

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I have updated my code with all related class and method. Thanks!

Comment: @Acetamide Outside the `do-while` loop, it should be like this:  `if (data.name.compareTo(head.data.name) < 0)` . This is the edge case that needs to be handled separately.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet OMG it works!!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: So lets hope your prof doesn't know about Google or Stackoverflow...

Comment: @brummfondel I guess she's fine with it, since this exercise requires more than she taught us.

Answer (score 1):

The following code implements an order based insertion into a linked list.  This of course assumes that the list is already sorted.  It is safe to make this assumption because the only way in your interface to add nodes to a linked list is via this method.

```
public static void addNode(Data data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data, head);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node current = head;
    while (current.next != null && data.name.compareTo(current.data.name) >= 0) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (current == head && data.name.compareTo(current.data.name) < 0) {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode.next = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Information has been added to the inventory.");
}
```

Comment: When I entered the second data, it shows error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think this handles the case when there is one item only, and the second item to be inserted is inserted at the head.

Comment: Nope still doesn't sort... I enter d, a, c, b in order then it display d,a,c,b to me. Also I'm using iterator implementation to display it too.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I updated my answer to handle this edge case.  There is probably a nicer way of doing this.

Comment: It did not sort the first node I think, I enter d,a,c,b in order and it gives me a,d,b,c ..

Comment: You never told us you needed to _sort_ the list.  My code _maintains_ insertion order but does not sort.

Comment: Umm. The title says to sort the list

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Umm...if `addNode()` maintains insertion order then how could a list possibly ever not be sorted?  Did you think about this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I actually agree with you. I assumed that the insertion will happen at the right place. So there is no need to implement a `sort` method and sort it separately. It is done inside `addNode( )`. So yeah, you are right :) i mixed up `sorting` with `order based insertion`

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your `Node` is not the one from java util LinkedList, right? Can you provide the implementation of it? Why does its constructor the `head` ?

You insert your new element at the begin and try to traverse forward. And at the end of your loop in your `current` is the first *greater* and `previous` the last smaller. Until now correct.

But afterwards, you never use the `Previous`, and sets the new element to your. You nead to insert it between `previous` and `current`. Something like that:

```
    if (previous == null)
      head = newData;
    else
      previous.next = newData;

    newData.next = current;
```

Comment: I see, got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. But as a structure for holding elements sorted, it's more suitable heap. In java, I would use PriorityQueue and just implement a Comparator for your data. It's much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a rich library for sorting for any collection of data

```
java.util.Collections.sort(YOURLIST_valiable)
```