# Inserting a number into a linked list and keeping it sorted while doing so in java

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting, insertion

I feel very confident that i'm right in this code. Logically, it makes sense to me but for some reason the program refuses to run past a certain point. I'm supposed to do this without using proprietary classes or hashtables. My list node is a basic singly linked list. Assuming i have a dummy list at first, 0, i'm able to add one number to the list but that is all. This is the method that will not work beyond adding the first number.

Assuming my list is 0 -> 2. and i'm trying to add 1.

```
public void insert(int newElement) {
    List marker = head;
    List temp = new List(newElement, null);

    if (head.next == null) {
        head.next = temp;
    } else {
        while (marker.next != null) {
            if (newElement < marker.next.value) {
                temp.next = marker.next;
                marker.next = temp;
                marker = marker.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if your head is 5 then add 0, you'll get a list of 5->0

Comment: So right off the bat I can think of a case that doesn't work with your code. You don't take into account that the inserted node can be less than the head. This immediately means that your list becomes unsorted. Fix that and if you have more questions come back and ask those.

Comment: If it helps, this is entirely an issue with your logic and not a subtlety or bug related to Java itself. Some immediate problems not yet mentioned are that the `while` loop will never end if `newElement >= marker.next.value`, and that an element could be attempted inserted multiple times because it doesn't stop after doing it once

Comment: I'm confident my code is right, but it's not doing what I want. Classic.

Comment: I saw my infinite loop as soon as I posted that and fixed the marker incrementing. For this class, we're using 0 as a dummy node and we're focused on simply being able to add positive integers in the list and sort them as you add them. Afterwords we're looking into not having dummy values and accounting for whether or not it'll go before the head or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List marker = head;
    List temp = new List(newElement, null);

    if (head.value > temp.value) {
        head.next = new List(head.value, null);
        head.value = newElement;
    }else if(head.next == null)
    {
        head.next = temp;
    }
    else {
        while (marker.next != null) {
            if (newElement < marker.next.value) {
                temp.next = marker.next;
                marker.next = temp;
                break; //we added the node, no need to continue looping
            }
            else //we need to iterate to the next node in the list until empty
            {
                marker = marker.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried using this. It seems like I'm still stuck. I added any value, and it works. But then any value beyond that doesn't seem to register.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insert(int val) {
    Item item = new Item(val);

    // the case when there is no item (not counting the dummy head)
    if (head.getNext() == null) {
        head.setNext(item);
        item.setNext(null);
    } else {
        // if there is at least one item....
        Item cursor = head.getNext();
        Item prev = cursor;

        // simply keep looping the list until the new value is less than a value in list
        // if the new value is greater than all the values in the list...
        // then the do-while loop will break when null is reached...
        // at the end of the list
        do {
            if (val < cursor.getVal()) {
                // break and insert
                break;
            }
            prev = cursor;
            cursor = cursor.getNext();
        } while (cursor != null);

        // insert the item
        item.setNext(cursor);

        // the case when the new value is the smallest and is to be inserted at head
        if (val < head.getNext().getVal()) {
            head = item;
        } else prev.setNext(item);
    }
}
```

This is your code snippet:

```
if (newElement < marker.next.value) {
    temp.next = marker.next;
    marker.next = temp;
    marker = marker.next;
}
```

Take a pencil and a paper and trace out this piece of code. You will see what's wrong with it. Take a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637006/2235972) answer and see the image attached. This is how you should really debug problems regarding linked lists. That image is not specific to your code, but it should give you an idea how to approach this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working and I'm currently testing it with good results. Can anyone find a problem with this code that i'm missing?

```
public void insert(int newElement) {
    List marker = head;
    List temp = new List(newElement, null);

    if (head.next == null) {
        head.next = temp;
    } else {
        for (marker = head; marker.next != null; marker = marker.next) {
            if (temp.value < marker.next.value) {
                temp.next = marker.next;
                marker.next = temp;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (marker.next == null && temp.value > marker.value) {
                marker.next = temp;

            } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Enter these values in order and print the output:  `3, 4, 2, 4, 1`

Comment: entered 3,4,2,4,1 and it worked out just fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: It doesn't add 4 twice but that's only because i didn't account for if it equals something that's already in the list but I'm sure I can get it from here!

Comment: Kudos to you for fixing your own problem. Now accept your (or anyone's) answer so that future visitor's don't invest their time to answer an already-solved question :)