# Linked list insert a node in sorted linked list

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

*emphasized text* i need to pass header of the LINKED LIST and data to be inserted in that linked list.assuming the list is in sorted order i need to check data from each  node and insert new node to give  newly sorted  list.

im getting null pointer exception ,, i need to know what im doing wrong

```
/*
  Insert Node at the end of a linked list 
  head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list
  Node is defined as 
  class Node {
     int data;
     Node next;
     Node prev;
  }
*/

Node SortedInsert(Node head,int data) {
    Node root= head;
    if(head==null){
        root.data=data;
        root.next=null;
        root.prev=null;

    }else if(head.data>data){
            Node newnode = new Node();
           newnode.data=data;
           newnode.next=head;
           newnode.prev=null;
            head.prev=newnode;
            root=newnode;
        }
    int k=0;
    while(head!=null && k==0){

        if(head.data<data && head.next.data>data && head.next!=null){
           Node temp=head.next;
           Node newnode = new Node();
           newnode.data=data;
           newnode.next=temp;
           newnode.prev=head;
           head.next=newnode;
           temp.prev=newnode;k++; break;
       }
        else if(head.data<data && head.next==null){
           //Node temp=head.next;
           Node newnode = new Node();
           newnode.data=data;
           newnode.next=null;
           newnode.prev=head;
           head.next=newnode;k++;break;
           //temp.prev=newnode;
       }else 
       {head=head.next;}

    }
  return root;
}
```

> im getting null pointer exception at second if statement inside while loop.

Comment: Consider the very first line in your `if`s: You say `head==null` and `root=head`. Then `root.data` is `null.data`.

Comment: In the future you should always detail which lines throw the error(s) to help us understand your code. And _please_ re-read your question before posting.

Comment: @bleistift2 sorry about that.my error message can be read only if the code lines are numbered   .  i have changed my code as u suggested but still facing same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939732/inserting-a-number-into-a-linked-list-and-keeping-it-sorted-while-doing-so-in-ja/40940375#40940375

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some errors in your code which might be giving `NullPointerException` So change it accordingly.

First mistake is here:

```
Node root= head;
if(head==null){
    root.data=data;
    root.next=null;
    root.prev=null;
}
```

So here you need to first create an object of Node class and assign it to root so code will look like :

```
Node root= head;
if(head==null){
    root=new Node();
    root.data=data;
    root.next=null;
    root.prev=null;
}
```

Another Mistake I encountered is in condition of `if(head.data<data && head.next.data>data && head.next!=null)`. 
Here you are should validate `head.next` before accessing it in `head.next.data`.
Suppose if `head.next` is `null` then the evaluation of `condition` of loop goes like this.

**1)** `head.data<data` so suppose this return `true` so we will check next condition.

**2)** `head.next.data>data` now if `head.next` is `null` then here condition would be `null.data` which will throw an `NullPointerException`. So here you should also check that `head.next` is not null. You are doing this is next condition but it is getting executed before validation it.

So here you just need to change order of the condition of `if` statement like: `if(head.data<data && head.next!=null && head.next.data>data)`.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Node root= head;
if(head==null){
    root.data=data;
```

here you are trying to set data for a null object
you should allocate memory for root first
e.g.

```
head = new Node();
root = head
//then continue your code
```

Comment: i did Node root= new Node();
     root= head;     still facing same issue.

Comment: may i ask why i cant set data to null object. the object values are null right? i can change to some integer...right?